# jConfirm message cannot work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

The confirmation popup always return true. Please advice the correction needed.

```
$('#btnDelete').click(function () {
    var check = false;
    var aCheckbox = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < aCheckbox.length; i++) {
        if (aCheckbox[i].type === 'checkbox' && aCheckbox[i].checked) {
            check = true;
        }
    }
    if (check === true) {
        return jConfirm('Do u really want to delete?', 'Confirmation');
    } else {
        jAlert("Please select serial number", 'Alert');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: }); extra braces close in your code are u know check the last line code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this help :

```
if (check === true) {
        var answer = confirm('Do u really want to delete?', 'Confirmation');
        if(answer)
           return true;
        else
           return false;
    } 
else {
        jAlert("Please select serial number", 'Alert');
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it creates problem you need to use third parameter as callback function of [jconfirm](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/) like,

```
if (check === true) {
    jConfirm('Do u really want to delete?', 'Confirmation', function(r) {
        jAlert('Confirmed: ' + r, 'Confirmation Results');
    });
    return false;
} else {
    .....
```

Also remove extra closing `});` from your code, see last two lines.